# UEFI boot not working afte succesful install - Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: grub2, uefi

I am not able to UEFI boot a computer after a successful USB install of Ubuntu 15.10. I prepared the bootable USB with the newest version of Rufus, using GPT for UEFI mode. After a successful OS install, the computer leads to the firmware on rebooting. In the firmware, UEFI Harddisk shows up as the first boot option. Boot is set to UEFI, fast boot, secure boot is disabled, quiet boot enabled. Legacy mode install is even worse, it leads to grub-rescue on rebooting after installing the OS.

Boot-repair did not resolve the problem either. Here is the bootInfo: http://paste.ubuntu.com/14442720/

My system: OS (Ubuntu 15.10), MB: ECS FM2A55, Processor A4 6300.I don't intend to dual boot this computer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your Boot Repair output looks correct, at least at first glance. Chances are the firmware on your computer is defective. I recommend you try going to the manufacturer's site and updating the firmware. (The manufacturer probably calls the firmware a "BIOS," although technically it isn't a BIOS.) If that fails, I recommend you return the motherboard and buy a new one from a different manufacturer, since you shouldn't be accepting defective merchandise. (Note that the defect is something that would be in all motherboards of that model with the same firmware version; I'm not talking about a sample-specific manufacturing defect.) If you return the computer, be sure to tell the manufacturer why you did so. They'll keep delivering junk if people keep accepting it; and if you don't tell them why you returned junk, they won't know what needs fixing.

If you really *MUST* keep that motherboard, you can work around the problem as follows:

1. Boot an Ubuntu emergency disk.
2. Mount `/dev/sda1` somewhere convenient -- say, `/mnt`.
3. Type `sudo cp -r /mnt/EFI/ubuntu /mnt/EFI/BOOT`.
4. Type `sudo mv /mnt/efi/BOOT/shimx64.efi /mnt/efi/BOOT/bootx64.efi`.

This procedure copies the boot loader to the fallback filename, which the firmware should launch when it fails to launch it under the name registered in NVRAM. This workaround, however, means that GRUB updates (that is, updates to GRUB, not updates to GRUB's configuration) won't be fully installed unless you repeat these steps.

Comment: Do not know if /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi does not exist if Boot-Repair creates one or not. I requested that it do suggested copy as above and ticking 'Use the standard EFI file' should work. https://bugs.launchpad.net/boot-repair/+bug/1531178  But since only Ubuntu installed, it may be booting, but video or other driver issue. Grub menu will not show by default. Can you press Escape on cold boot and get a grub menu?

Comment: I went ahead and installed Fedora 23 instead. Worked like a champ on the same setup! Must have been a problem with Ubuntu. Thanks a lot for looking into this though.

Comment: Actually, Fedora jumps through hoops to get itself working on defective EFIs. In the process, it sometimes creates new problems. (That's a common theme in the EFI world -- the ugly hacks used to work around one problem usually create new ones.)