# Help with Ubuntu Single Boot: Grub doesn't Load: Report Attached

Tags: boot, 16.04, grub2, uefi, grub-efi

The link boot report is : https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Kz4-jmG-BwyT-6SAk0K80ThI3ICyqoRbxUUh_a8NQfI/edit?usp=sharing.

The single boot Ubuntu 16.04's grub doesn't load.

Comment: My system is Uefi.

Comment: What hardware? Is there any error message?

Comment: It *should* be working. Try booting the Ubuntu installer in "try before installing" mode, then open a Terminal, then type `sudo efibootmgr`. (You may need to do a `sudo apt-get install efibootmgr` first.) If the `efibootmgr` output lacks a `BootOrder` line, as I suspect it will, your firmware is defective. In that case, see [this question and my answer to it.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/718861/uefi-boot-not-working-afte-succesful-install-ubuntu-15-10)